# Can we say 'here goes your husband' or 'there comes your husband'?

Tags: sentence-construction

We can say 'here comes your husband' and 'there goes our bus' so why not 'here goes your husband' or 'there comes your husband'?

Also, am I correct that "comes" means approaching the speaker and "goes" means moving away from the speaker and "here" and "there" denote the position relative to the speaker?

Comment: It is possible to find a use for **here goes**, like "Here goes Pat with those humble brags again." And there comes a time. But not suitable for actual direction.

Answer (score 3):

*Here comes your husband* draws attention to the fact that he is *coming here* (he's walking towards us). *Here goes your husband* doesn't make sense. However, there is an expression [Here goes!](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/here-goes) that you might use before starting an activity that is new to you. (It doesn't have a logical meaning.)

*There goes* points out someone or something that is moving away from, or past, the speaker. You might say *There goes our bus* if you had seen it drive past the bus stop before you had got there to stop it (it's going away from us). If you are birdwatching, you might say *There it goes* when a bird you are interested in flies past. *There* usually refers to a place away from the speaker, so it would sound odd to say *there comes.*

Comment: Why 'Here goes your husband' doesn't make sense?

Comment: Because _here goes_ is very rarely used literally: it almost always refers to a process or endeavour being started, especially a risky one.

Comment: And because if you say it literally the two words contradict each other. *Here* implies movement towards. *Goes* implies movement away from.

Comment: I can't see this contradiction. If you are moving you are moving away from something and getting closer to something. Additionally, doesn't "here" simply indicate the location of an object?

Comment: As you say, _goes_ means moving away from the speaker, so it doesn't match with _here_ which means 'in the speaker's location'. We say 'come here' (to where I am) and 'go there' (to another place).

Comment: What if we are at a bus stop and our bus is about to leave? Our bus is in the speaker's location (at the bus stop) and it is moving away from the speaker. Can I say 'here goes our bus'? You can imagine that we were a few seconds late and the bus leaves at the same moment we arrived at the bus stop.

Comment: No - as I said in my answer, we use _there goes_ for something moving away from us (from 'here' to 'there').

Comment: I don't get it on the one hand you say that 'here/there' means place but when we move on to examples you start treating 'here/there' as if it means movement.

Comment: They can indeed mean both! There exist the words _hither_ (to this place) and _thither_ (to that place), but they are seldom used in current English except in the idiom _hither and thither_ which describes people moving about in a disorganised way.  We use _here_  to mean both 'in this place' and 'to this place'.

Comment: So "here goes" doesn't work because "here" means movement from that place to this place and "goes" means moving away from the speaker?

Does "there comes" not work for an analogous reason?

Comment: Exactly - you've got it!

Answer (score 1):

here comes and there goes can be used with anything that moves.

"Am I correct that "comes" means approaching the speaker and "goes" means moving away from the speaker and "here" and "there" denote the position relative to the speaker?"

YES.